# How to get the exact number of multibyte characters?

Tags: php, multibyte

I tried:

```
mb_strlen('普通话');
strlen('普通话');
```

both of them output 9,while in fact there are only 3 characters.

What's the right way to count characters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should make sure to specify the encoding in the second parameter

ie

```
mb_strlen('普通话', 'UTF-8');
```

see the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to the mb string extension this also works (and I believe it's faster):

```
strlen(utf8_decode('普通话')); // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

One Chinese character doesn't equal to one ascii character. 
mb_strlen is the right way to count multi-byte characters if the string in UTF-8 encoded.

see here:
http://www.herongyang.com/PHP-Chinese/Multibyte-UTF-8-mb_strlen.html